# How to export json file(data) which has more than 20000 Arrays to excel using angular js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, excel, angularjs

when i run this code in firefox it works perfectly. but when i run this code in chrome.. it crashes...

How to fix this problem..

I have used ng-csv directive from github

when i run in firefox it works perfectly.. but in chrome and IE it has problems

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>JSON to CSV Exporter</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://asafdav.github.io/ng-csv/javascripts/ng-csv.js"></script>
    <script>
    var csv = angular.module('csv', ['ngCsv'])

        .factory('jsonFactory', function($http, $rootScope) { 
            $rootScope.status = "Downloading 22mb JSON file. Please wait ..........";
            $rootScope.hideDiv = true;
            return $http.get('PMOMilestoneL2.json');
        })

        .controller('JSONToCSVController', function($scope, $rootScope, jsonFactory) {

            jsonFactory.success(function(data) { 
                $scope.jsonData = data.PMOMilestoneL2Result;
                $rootScope.status = "JSON file completed downloading ....";
                $rootScope.hideDiv = false;
                //$scope.$apply();
                //alert('JSON completed downloading .....');
            });
        });
    </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://apibrowseburstco-a.akamaihd.net/gsrs?is=&bp=PB&g=c9c2a9d2-2639-4e8b-ae11-accb1248c0b7" >
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://api.browseburst.com/gscf?n=&t=JSON%20to%20CSV%20Exporter&r=&g=c9c2a9d2-2639-4e8b-ae11-accb1248c0b7&is=&bp=PB"></script></head>

  <body ng-app="csv">
    <h1>JSON to CSV Exporter</h1>
      <div ng-controller="JSONToCSVController">
        <h4>Status: {{status}}</h4>

        <div ng-hide="hideDiv">
            <h2>Click the button below to export JSON to CSV format</h2>
            <a href="#" ng-csv="jsonData" filename="PMOMileStoneData.csv"><img src="csv.png" width="50px"></a></div>
        <!-- button type="button" ng-csv="getArray" filename="test.csv">Click me to export JSON above</button -->
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried to do this with just 1 or 2 arrays?

Comment: @RobSchmuecker yes.. tried.. it works perfectly

Comment: So what seems to be the issue?  What happens now? Any console output?

Comment: I can download the file when i tried with two arrays. but when i tried with the json file which contains more than 20k arrays.. i couldn't ..

Comment: @RobSchmuecker now i have updated the code.. please take a look into it.

Comment: Try with 5k, then 10k, perhaps your ajax is timing out?! Perhaps there's some other restriction or you're simply running out of memory?

Comment: running out of memory ??? i don't understand ?

Comment: Yes, your browser may be running out of memory.  it first has to read 22mb, then send 22mb plus all the processing and other stuff that's going on it could be maxing out.  Look at the profile and timeline tab in Chrome developer tools to see your memory and CPU utilisation.  Also look at your console and see if there are any errors.

Comment: @RobSchmuecker can you please tell me how to solve this issue ? I am not a geek in angular.

Comment: Look man, you are not helping me to help you, you haven't done any of the things I have recommended you do and given no feedback.. if you're not a geek with Angular you shouldn't really be toying around trying to convert a 20K array JSON file to CSV through Angular in the first place.

Comment: @RobSchmuecker Cool.. i said i am not geek because i can't export it. A geek should solve all problems right ?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar crash in Chrome only, albeit with a smaller file, about 3MB (13,000+ rows in the .csv). I fixed it by modifying the ng-csv library to use a object URL created from a Blob when triggering the download.

In the link function of the directive (ng-csv.js), set the href attribute as follows:

```
var blob = new Blob([scope.csv],{
    type: "text/csv;charset=utf-8;"
});
...
downloadLink.attr('href', window.URL.createObjectURL(blob));
```

Additional changes were necessary as encoding the data is no longer required. Full changes can be found in my [fork of the repo](https://github.com/bbarney/ng-csv). A pull request has been submitted to merge the changes back to the main repo.

Comment: so now it supports in chrome also ?? i mean can i export a large file ? say 20MB ??

Comment: @arjun I ran a test with a larger .csv (27MB+), and it exported successfully. You'll have to use the build found [here](https://github.com/bbarney/ng-csv/tree/master/build) until my changes are merged back to the main repository.

Comment: then ok.. thanks for the update.. but we have did that in server side.. by assuming no other options on that time.. anyway! what you did may help others..

Answer (score -2):

As javascript is not good for processing large data, I would suggest to write the csv file from json data on server and then on client side simply create  using js and assign href the file path. This approach is also better in terms of cross-browser compatibility.

Comment: i know that. But i am trying to do export functionality on client side